# How to write a function to disable console.log and can be required in other react file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Below is my `static.js` file:

```
var Helper = {
    console.log: function(){
    },

    Login: function(){
        var name;
        var password;
        //rest of the code
    }
}

module.exports = Helper;
```

And below is my test.js file:

```
var Helper = require('./static.js');
console.log("Test");
```

And I got some error  from this line `console.log: function(){}` in static.js file.

What I want is nothing will show on terminal even I `console.log('Test')` because I write `function(){}` for `console.log`.

Is anything I did wrong?

Comment: What is the "some error" you get?

Answer (score 1):

Just overwrite console.log function in your script:

```
console.log = function() {};
```

Overwrite other log function too:

```
window.console.log = window.console.debug = window.console.info = window.console.error = function () {
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just figured out how to fix this problem.

I rewrite the function like below..

```
DisableConsole: function(DEBUG){
    if(!DEBUG){
        if(!window.console) window.console = {};
        var methods = ["log", "debug", "warn", "info"];
        for(var i=0;i<methods.length;i++){
            console[methods[i]] = function(){};
        }
    }
}
```

and require this static.js file in my top component which mean every component under this main component will also include this static.js.

and call this function in the very beginning.

```
AppHelpers.DisableConsole(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have this error because you're trying to create an object with a key `console.log`, but it is a syntax violation when using object literal syntax, because `.` dot is a special symbol.

Even if it worked, you wouldn't achieve what you want, since `console.log` is a global function and you are working with just a custom created object.

What you actually want to do is to silence the global function like this `console.log = function() {};`. Beware, however, that you won't be able to restore the old behaviour if you didn't save the original function: `var oldConsoleLog = console.log`.

There is also [a module](https://github.com/jlenoble/muter) for it.